# XForms: Delete trigger in table row (repeat)

Tags: repeat, xforms, orbeon

I am using an XForms' repeat to build up a table (very similar to http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xforms-repeat). Each row should get a delete trigger to remove it. The following code does only delete the selected item, is it somehow possible to use the current repeat index as a value for at?

```
<xforms:delete nodeset="employees" at="index('employee-repeat')"/>
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: hmm - i would expect this code to work, provided that the `trigger` is inside the `repeat`. Activating the trigger should select its repeat, so `index()` should point to the current repeat item. Maybe you could add the complete `repeat` code?

Comment: As @tohuwawohu was saying, I would also expect this to work, as when you click on the button, you make the employee on the line where the delete button is the current one. But as mentioned in my answer below, it is simpler in that case to use `.` to refer to the current employee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a delete trigger for every row, then you don't need to use the `index()` function. Instead, just refer to the current node, as in:

```
<xforms:repeat nodeset="employees">
    ...
    <xforms:trigger>
        <xforms:label>Delete</xforms:label>
        <xforms:delete ev:event="DOMActivate" nodeset="."/>
    </xforms:trigger>
</xforms:repeat>
```

If you had just one trigger for the whole repeat (i.e. at the beginning and/or end of the table listing the employees), then you could use `index()` to refer to the "current" employee. That means that users would first need to click somewhere on that employee to make it the current one, and then click on the button. This is a somewhat unusual web UI, and so I would rather have one delete button per employee or use checkboxes for users to select which employees they want to act on.